# Salesforce1: Change header

Tags: salesforce1-app

Is it possible to add text or button to Salesforce1 header?

[image: Salesforce1 Navigation Header]

From the document [Salesforce1 Developer Cheat Sheet](http://res.cloudinary.com/hy4kyit2a/image/upload/s1_dev_cheatsheet_cheatsheet.pdf) it seems that it is not feasible but maybe there are some known workarounds. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try using a css hack..

Comment: @JigarShah can you show an example of how a css hack would work?